# Regex Javascript (Must have 1 number and characters)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having problems to get this to work.

The following javascript regex expects at least one number in the string.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/;
```

But, I also want to allow a comma (",") and a period (".")

I tried various options but it doesn't work. Any help, please ?

Comment: Where in the regex do you want to allow `,` and `.`? What did you try?

Comment: @denis Seriously accept answer to encourage people helping you and others.

Answer (score 3):

This would work:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9., ]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9., ]*$/
```

Comment: Dot is *not* a special character inside a character class.

Comment: @MarkByers You are right, I have always escaped it there too. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

How about a shorter solution:

```
/[\w\s,.]*\d+[\w\s,.]*/
```

There's no need for the ^ and $ in  this case.

Comment: This isn't the same. It will also accept (for example) underscores and tabs, which the original expression doesn't accept.

Answer (score 0):

Just add those characters to the appropriate character classes:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9,. ]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9,. ]*$/
```

Here's a more concise way to write it using a lookahead:

```
/^(?=.*?[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9,. ]+$/
```